# Search for a text string and return the text string in following row using R

Tags: r

I converted a few thousand PDFs into .txt files in R and I'm trying to parse out useful information. One of the strings I need happens to consistently be located after "please contact:" like so-

> This is the document header of the file
>   If you have any questions please contact:
>   Contact Name

I would like to extract Contact Name and place it into its own column in a separate table per text file, along with other information. This part of the document varies in location but will always be preceded by "contact:"

I tried using:

```
str_trim(sapply(strsplit(textdata[grepl("contact:",textdata)], ":"), "[", 2)[1], side = "left")
```

but this does not work because it is not skipping to the following line.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your data and an example of your desired output? From what you posed it's hard to be sure what exactly you're trying to extract

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example in r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure to include reproducible input and output/errors you'd get. Cheers.

Comment: The short answer is that you can use `str_match_all` and [regex](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/modifiers.html) with `multiline = TRUE`. But we need to see better example data with all possible patterns. For example, is the name always on the next line after "contact:"